# Delete commas within numbers

Tags: numbering, calculations

To use `package{calc}` for calculation, number should not include any commas. So I tried to use `\def\commatonone #1,#2.00 {#1#2}` to get the number without commas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\def\commatonone #1,#2.00 {#1#2}

\begin{document}
\commatonone 192,150.00
\end{document}
```

[image: 192500]

However, if I use command to define the number, error happens.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\def\commatonone #1,#2.00 {#1#2}
\newcommand{\BASESALARYAMOUNT}{149,500.00}
\newcommand{\PREVIOUSBASESALARYAMOUNT}{110,000.00}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{BASESALARYDIFFERENCE}
\addtocounter{BASESALARYDIFFERENCE}{\commatonone\BASESALARYAMOUNT}
\addtocounter{BASESALARYDIFFERENCE}{\commatonone\PREVIOUSBASESALARYAMOUNT}

\end{document}
```

```
Error: Paragraph ended before \commatonone was complete. []
```

Are there any way to fix it? Or any better way to do the calculation with the number having commas already? (numbers are input from other files, so cannot change from raw data). And I hope it can be used for numbers like `xxx.xx`, `xxx,xxx.xx`, `xxx,xxx,xxx.xx` etc.

Comment: Could you add an example of calculations you're performing?

Comment: how are the numbers input from files ? perhaps a ``\catcode`, 9 `` before the `\input` (**and** ``\catcode44 12 `` after) could work, depending on the file contents. But you also have the issue of the decimal part `.00` which can not be used, even with `calc` as is in a `\addtocounter`. (this is why David's [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282985/4686) removes it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for any number of commas and more than one level of macro expansion. It assumes that `.00` is always present, making it optional would also be possible but complicate the coding a bit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\def\commatonone{\expandafter\zappointzerozero
                 \romannumeral`\^^@}

\def\zappointzerozero#1.00{\zapcomma#1,!}
\def\zapcomma#1,#2{#1\ifx!#2\else#2\expandafter\zapcomma\fi}


\newcommand{\BASESALARYAMOUNT}{149,500.00}
\newcommand{\PREVIOUSBASESALARYAMOUNT}{110,000.00}
\newcommand{\BIGSALARYAMOUNT}{110,110,000.00}

\newcommand\extramacro{\BASESALARYAMOUNT}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{BASESALARYDIFFERENCE}
\addtocounter{BASESALARYDIFFERENCE}{\commatonone\BASESALARYAMOUNT}
\addtocounter{BASESALARYDIFFERENCE}{\commatonone\BIGSALARYAMOUNT}
\addtocounter{BASESALARYDIFFERENCE}{\commatonone\extramacro}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The following minor modification seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\def\commatononei#1,#2.00{#1#2}
\def\commatonone#1{\expandafter\commatononei#1}
\newcommand{\BASESALARYAMOUNT}{149,500.00}
\newcommand{\PREVIOUSBASESALARYAMOUNT}{110,000.00}

\begin{document}

\commatonone\BASESALARYAMOUNT

\newcounter{BASESALARYDIFFERENCE}
\addtocounter{BASESALARYDIFFERENCE}{\commatonone\BASESALARYAMOUNT}
\addtocounter{BASESALARYDIFFERENCE}{\commatonone\PREVIOUSBASESALARYAMOUNT}


\end{document}
```

(The only change is removing the spaces from your definition of `\commantonone` and repackaging it in `\commatononei`, this new command is then called by `\commatonone` which includes an `\expandafter` to handle the case where the number is defined by a command.)

Comment: I am not well-versed enough in TeX internals to explain to you exactly what went wrong with your original try. This 'solution' is arrived at from the "guess-and-try" department.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea how to make it work for any numbers with possible two or more commas like `xxx.xx`, `xxx,xxx.xx`, `xxx,xxx,xxx.xx` etc.

Comment: @Joe: David's answer is what I would try (by recursion), if limited to the world of TeX.